# Passar um array de objetos para um component no angular 8

Tags: angular, ionic

Boa tarde,

Gostaria de uma ajuda para passar um array de objetos para um component no angular 8.

No caso tenho um formulário que utilizo em duas partes no meu código em um deles preciso desse formulário em branco e no outro preciso que ele venha preenchido com informações do banco.

O em branco é para cadastrar novos serviços e o preenchido é para editar um serviço.

Então quando faço a chamada no arquivo HTML para carregar essas informações não consigo passar esses dados para o component.

Já tentei com o @Input, mas sem sucesso.

**Aqui faço a chamada do component app-form-service:**

```
<ion-content>
  <app-form-service></app-form-service>
</ion-content>
```

**Aqui é o component onde preciso carregar as informações do DB:**

```
<ion-content>
  <form action="">
    <div class="photo-container">
      <img
        src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/38/PNG/512/photo_picture_4894.png"
        alt="logo"
      />
    </div>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Categorias</ion-label>
      <ion-select>
        <ion-select-option value="01">Cabelo</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="02">Pedicure</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="03">Manicure</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="04">Pele</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="05">Sobrancelha</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="06">Maquiagem</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="07">Bronzeamento</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating">Título do serviço</ion-label>
      <ion-input></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating">Descrição</ion-label>
      <ion-input></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating">Preço</ion-label>
      <ion-input></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating">Tempo do serviço (em minutos)</ion-label>
      <ion-input></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-button type="submit" expand="block">Cadastrar</ion-button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Mas vc não utiliza um **model** pra isso?

Comment: @LeAndrade poderia mostrar um exemplo de como utilizar o model?

Comment: Basicamente um model é uma classe Javascript (Typescript) que serve de modelo(espelho) para os dados retornados pelo Banco (Api), vc instancia a classe e pode usá-la em formulários, espelhando os dados e enviando o model para o banco. Da uma pesquisada na diretiva do Angular chamada **ngModel**.

Comment: Você poderia compartilhar o código TypeScript? Nos seletores dos seus componentes (markups 'xml') não ví os atributos para enviar informações do componente pai (parent) para o component filho(child) via anotação @Input.

Answer (score 1):

Suponha que você tenha um componente "Pai" (parent component)

```
**componente-pai.ts**
----------


@Component({
    selector: 'componente-pai',
    templateUrl: './componente-pai.html',
})
export class ComponentePai implements OnInit {
    public valorEnviado: string;
```

Abaixo o template (markup) do componente pai:

```
**componente-pai.html**
----------

<componente-filho [valorRecebido]="valorEnviado"></componente-filho>
```

E um componente "Filho" (child component)

```
**componente-filho.ts**
----------

@Component({
    selector: 'componente-filho',
    templateUrl: './componente-filho.html',
})
export class ComponenteFilho implements OnInit {
    @Input() public valorRecebido: string;
```

Abaixo o template (markup) do componente filho:

```
**componente-filho.html**
----------

<h3>Mostrando valor recebido: {{ valorRecebido }}</h3>
```

Comment: Para passar um Array de objetos a lógica é exatamente a mesma, ao invés de passar uma `string` você irá passar um `Array<SeuTipoDeObjeto>`